# The right way to implement Named group for choices in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm a newbie and I'm wonder how to make choices into named group, in django documentation it says "You can also collect your available choices into named groups that can be used for organizational purposes". Based on documentation i try to make some model below

```
python_2_unicode_compatible
class Music(models.Model):
    Media_Choices=[('Audio',(('vinyl','Vinyl'),
                    ('cd','CD'),))
                   ,('Video',(('vhs','VHS Tape'),
                              ('dvd','DVD'),)),
                   ('unknown','Unknown'),]

    Music_Media=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=Media_Choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_Music_Media_display()
```

There is no problem when i make migrations and create objects for my model, my question is how to acces the tuple of the group choices (especially human-readable name for an option) when querying? Is it my code right? (the way to implement choices into named group), correct me if i'm wrong. Thank you. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: It seems good to me. What's the problem are your facing?

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem I want to acces the option of the group, lets say i have Music objects with Media_Choices 'Audio', i'm wonder can i display the 'Audio' option ('Vinyl' or 'CD' in this case) when querying (how to acces it via Music object), is it possible..?

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve Human readable names you will need to use `Model.get_FOO_display()` method.

In your case, this should do the trick.

```
#lets say song is a Music object
print song.get_Music_Media_display()
```

[Here is more documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) for this method.

Comment: thank for the thought, yes i know how to retrieve Human readable names. I mean in this case how to retrive human readable names of available choices from named group. Like my Media_choices is "Audio", if i implement your suggest the human readble names only retrieve the "Audio", how can i retrieve the choices of Audio ("Vinyl" and / or "CD"), is it possible, if possible how....? Thank you

Comment: I think the grouping is only for organizational purpose. I don't think you can assign them to an object. You can assign one of 'vhs', 'dvd','cd','vinyl' or 'unknown'. Not an 'audio' or 'video'. Think like this, When you create a record in table Music, you are trying to constrain it to take one of these 5 options as column value. Now, if you want to retrieve relationship data of what kind of media is a 'vinyl' ?, your database should ideally store this information and not the schema/python code. So may be think on lines of creating a table that holds types of media.